# How to change the sequence of some variables in a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, analysis

I have a dataframe that has 100 variables `va1--var100`. I want to bring `var40`, `var20`, and `var30` to the front with other variables remain the original order. I've searched online, methods like

```
1: df[[var40, var20, var30, var1....]]
2: columns= [var40, var20, var30, var1...]
```

all require to specify all the variables in the dataframe. With 100 variables exists in my dataframe, how can I do it efficiently?

I am a SAS user, in SAS, we can use a retain statement before the set statement to achieve the goal. Is there a equivalent way in python too?

Thanks

Comment: If you just want those columns, then `df[[var20, var30, var40]]` will do the trick. Otherwise, you can do something like `df[sorted(df.columns, key=lambda x: x not in {var20, var30, var40})]`.

Comment: @Andrew Thank you so much for your answer, it works. Now I have another question, what if I want them in the order of var30, var40,var20, var1, var2.....?   I will also update the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with a conditional list comprehension:

```
first_cols = ['var30', 'var40', 'var20']

df = df.reindex(first_cols + [col for col in df.columns if col not in first_cols], 
                axis = 'columns')
```